# Refer to Generic type in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

With the following class structure:

```
abstract class GenericClass<T: Fragment> {
  protected lateinit var fragment: T

  fun anOperation(){
     //do something
  }
}

class ConcreteA: GenericClass<AFragment> {

}

class ConcreteB: GenericClass<BFragment>{
}
```

How can I achieve this?

```
fun useFragment(f:GenericClass){

   f.anOperation()

}
```

When I declare the `useFragment` function I get "`One type argument expected for class GenericClass`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You give the method its own type argument:

```
fun <T> useFragment(f: GenericClass<T>) {
   f.anOperation()
}
```

Notice the `<T>` after `fun`.

Kotlin doesn't have raw types, so you *need* to specify a generic type for `GenericClass`. You can also use the wildcard:

```
fun useFragment(f: GenericClass<*>) {
   f.anOperation()
}
```

In this case, there's no difference.

Also, the inheritance in your question is invalid - `GenericClass` is a final class and cannot be extended. You should add the `open` modifier to `GenericClass`.

You might even want to make it `abstract` instead, as it doesn't look like it should be used on its own.

Comment: nice explanation